# é showing up as &eacute in TextEdit

Tags: html, macos

I am opening a text file using Mac's TextEdit that has `&eacute;` in it. `&eacute;` is supposed to be showing up as é instead.

Is there a way to make TextEdit read it as é?

Comment: You should press **Format/Make Plain Text (⇧⌘T)** to switch to plain mode. BTW, this question would be more suitable on [apple.se].

Comment: @the4kman I just tried pressing the above command, the &eacute; is still appearing in the text. I also tried using other text editors such as BBEdit but &eacute; still appears.